# QueryDSL 4.1.4, Jpa GROUP BY Date

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have troubles on grouping my query by date. I need to consolidate some data in daily manner in `QueryDSL 4.1.4`. There is almost none of documentation and examples since Query DSL got an update `4.X`

Desired output

```
2018-02-02   |   SUM(some_field)
2018-02-03   |   SUM(some_field)
```

`.groupBy(qItem.dateField.dayOfMonth())` is not an option.

Maybe I should parse row sql somehow into `queryDSL`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself:

`GROUP BY "DATE_FORMAT(...)"`

In case of query DSL

`DateTemplate formattedDate = Expressions.dateTemplate(LocalDateTime.class, "DATE_FORMAT({0}, {1})", queryItem.timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y");`

```
query.select(...).groupBy(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Can we group by week with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @krzakov

Inspired by you, i got to do it in QueryDSL version 4.4.0 with:

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("DATE_FORMAT({0}, '%d/%m/%Y')", queryItem.date)
```

`dateTemplate` didn't workout for me.